# Can I assign a null value to an anonymous type property?

Tags: c#

I have the following in WebAPI that is converted to a JSON string and sent to the client:

```
return Ok(new
    {
        Answer = "xxx",
        Text = question.Text,
        Answers = question.Answers.Select((a, i) => new
        {
            AnswerId = a.AnswerId,
            AnswerUId = i + 1,
            Text = a.Text
        })
    });
```

Now I realize that I would like to assign the value null to Answer.  However this gives me a message saying

```
cannot assign <null> to anonymous type property.
```

Is there a way I can do this without having to define a class just so I can assign the null?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. This is useful, specific question with a simple answer. The linked question covers it, but is about dealing with an array.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Absolutely - you just need to cast the `null` value to the right type so that the compiler knows which type you want for that property. For example:

```
return Ok(new {
    Answer = (string) null,
    Text = ...,
    ...
});
```

Comment: Is (string) null really different from (int) null ?

Comment: @Anshul: Well `(int) null` isn't valid... but if you picked a type that *was* valid, then yes, they're different as they have different compile-time types, which means the anonymous types in the result would have different property types.

Comment: "Well (int) null isn't valid" -- Not sure why I didn't realize that. Of course. Thanks for your answer. Makes sense.

Comment: Great!

Remembering that for some primitive and boolean types, the null value is not allowed.

Comment: it should be (string?)null now

Comment: @TimurLemeshko: That depends on whether you're in a nullable context or not. I'm *definitely* not going to go back over thousands of code answers to make changes which could just as easily break some users.