# C# .NET how null is casting in anonymous type?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, conditional-operator, anonymous-types

This code will not compile:

```
        var x = new {
            Property = null,
        };
```

With following exception: Cannot assign null to anonymous type property

But this will work fine:

```
        var someBool = false;
        var x = new {
            Property = someBool ? "value" : null,
        };
```

I think there is implicit casting something like this - (string)null but not exactly sure.

So I would like to know more about this case and how this works **internally** (I didn't find any article explaining this)

Comment: Really? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851913/can-i-assign-a-null-value-to-an-anonymous-type-property

Comment: My main question is how this works internally

Comment: So read the answer carefully: "so that the compiler knows which type you want for that property".

Answer (score 5):

Compiler needs to determine type for anonymous type's properties which can't be done from just `null` (though you can argue about using `object` in this case but see the following quote), on the contrary [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) has a type (see the linked docs explaining how compiler determines it), which is `string` in case of `someBool ? "value" : null`.

From [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types) doc:

> The expression that is used to initialize a property cannot be `null`, an anonymous function, or a pointer type.

Comment: `string?` actually.