# How do I convert Union and Null as Col Sql query to Linq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

`SELECT  *, NULL AS purchaseOrderItemId, NULL AS isOrdered, NULL AS orderedDate, NULL AS orderNote FROM t1 UNION SELECT  *, NULL AS orderItemId FROM t2`

I want to convert this to Linq query.

This is what I got so far, but getting null casting error.

```
 var query = DBContext.t1
                    .Select( x => x, new
                    {
                        purchaseOrderItemId = null,
                        isOrdered = null,
                        orderedDate = null,
                        orderNote = null
                    })
                    .Union(
                    DBContext.t2
                    .Select( x => x, new
                    {
                        orderItemId = null
                    }
                    )
```

How can I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I assign a null value to an anonymous type property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851913/can-i-assign-a-null-value-to-an-anonymous-type-property)

Comment: In addition to casting `null` to a type, your unioned projections need to be the same type. For anonymous types, they have to have the same "shape" to be the same type, meaning the same properties with the same types for each property.

Comment: the columns with Null are not existing in from table but existing in the other table which unions.

Comment: They don't have to exist. This is a projection. That makes them exist in the resulting data set.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I tried with (int) null and stuff for each nulls though, but says it’s not valid.

Comment: You need `(int?)null` because `int` is not nullable but `int?` is.

Comment: i’ll try that thanks a lot!

Comment: Even this will not compile, only EF Core 8 can handle this.